# Set custom font for unicode characters in iPhone

Tags: iphone, unicode, uilabel, custom-font

I have a @"¾ÕÁõ ¦ºöÂ ¿£ Å¢ÕõÒÅ¡Â¡¸" string and a font to read it in **.ttf** format. I tried with the following code but the font is not getting displayed in `UILabel`. Can any one help me to find a solution for this please?

This is what I have tried:

```
FontLabel *label = [[FontLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 0, 0) fontName:@"ELCOT-Kanchi" pointSize:20.0f];
[label setText:@"¾ÕÁõ ¦ºöÂ ¿£ Å¢ÕõÒÅ¡Â¡¸"];
[label sizeToFit];
```

But I don't get the results.

I have also added the font to my resource file and included in info plist under Fonts Provided By Application array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi clean your build and make sure the font is added on your project's copy resources bundle have a look into attached screenshot.

[image]

I hope this will be helpful for you , Happy Coding :)